# What is the python equivalent for names() function in R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I have a code in R, where in the data frame "inputdata" there are multiple columns, and we are replacing the word "new" with "old" in the entire data frame:

```
names(inputData)[names(inputData)=="new"] <- "old"
```

How do I perform the same function in python, im a newbie in python ;-;

Comment: `df.columns` is the equivalent of `names(df)`

Comment: First, lets hope your dataframe has only one column named `new` otherwise it will be ill-defined. Note that the Base R dataframes can have multiple columns with the same naming. This is not acceptable, yet R supports it. Second, you are only changing new to old. thus `df.rename({'new':'old'}, axis = 1, inplace = True)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to the world of python. Try this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

for e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df.replace(0, 5)
```

BTW if you are looking for just column names update then do below:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('new', 'old')
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. OP is changing the name of the dataframe and not the values

Comment: He asked for data, isn't ? If not yes this is totally wrong

Comment: No, OP asked to replace the name

Comment: Cool edited my answer for both case. Thank You

Comment: That is still not correct. That will change everything that containes new. OP is only interested in the column named `new` not in columns like `new_mean` etc. Your code will replace `new_mean` to `old_mean` etc

Comment: Yes i am aware of that. but changing just 1 new to old is straight forward action and he has mentioned its spread throughout the dataframe so i will this as it is.

Comment: Note that they use `==` neaning there is one column whose name is EXACTLY `new` not many columns